# How do I associate a model with a session via a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose my site stores articles where each article is associated to the user who created it. I want to allow unauthenticated users to create an article, then login/signup at which point the article they created (before logging in/signing up) gets associated to their user instance.

My plan for tackling this was, I would have a session field in my `Article` model that associates an article to a session. So, when a user logs in I could get all the articles he created in that session and then set their 'user' foreign key field appropriately.

What's the best way for me to store the session as a field in my `Article` model?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    session = ...?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way round. Instead of storing the session key in the model, you should be storing the article ID in the session; then, on login, you can pop that ID out of the session, get the associated article, and set the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use CharField to store request.session.session_key in it.